# What is the most expensive regularly scheduled flight?

Tags: air-travel, factoids

What seat on a regularly scheduled flight is the most expensive?  I'm assuming it will be some first (or higher) class seat on a long-haul premium airline, but I'm not sure which trip can lay claim to being the most lucrative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arguably the flight from New York City and Mumbai on Etihad is the [most expensive flight](http://www.travelandleisure.com/travel-tips/airlines-airports/most-expensive-flight-world) in the world.

> A round-trip ticket would cost a staggering $76,000 (£52,000) at
>   single or double occupancy.

This is because the ticket is for "The Residence", which is an actual three-room suite on the plane. A slew of various services and amenities come with the ticket.

Comment: Definitely on my bucket list.

Comment: Somebody (who was apparently comp'd for the coverage) did a Youtube video on the experience.  I thought to myself, if you took away the foldout gadgets and the TV and added a bed, this could be an Amtrak sleeping car compartment.  And a lot less privacy, you sure couldn't take a girl back to the room.

Answer (score 3):

The direct flight from JFK to London *City* is no slouch either.  The spiritual successor of the Concorde, with flights numbers BA 1 and BA 2, it saves time by dropping you in London proper instead of out at Heathrow.  Cost is $5000-$10,000, and the entire airplane is first class.  (Other flights which involve stops and plane changes are in the $700 range.)

Equipmentwise, it has been downgraded from the incomparable Concorde to the ignominious Airbus 318 (the mini-mini-A320) - and being all-first-class means capacity is considerably less than the 100-seat Concorde.  However this allows it to grease into the tiny runway at LCY.  It cannot take off with full fuel, so westbound, it stops briefly at Shannon for fuel.

Comment: While BA001/002 are usually more expensive than LHR-JFK business class flights (and I think that's the relevant comparison, given the seats offered), it's not usually that much more expensive. If you can book a few months in advance and stay over a weekend, I'm seeing the A318 flights for around £1,900, which is around what you'd pay for business class for London-NY on most airlines. Getting any seat on the plane is more expensive than normal, yes, because it's all business class, but it's not especially expensive comparing apples to apples.

Comment: @ZachLipton Ah so you're right, it is 4-across.  For some reason I thought it was all the full-on cubicles. It is only 32 seats on the entire plane, can't imagine how they can make it on GBP1900 a seat.