# Why does London have 6 international airports?

Tags: uk, airports, london

Why does London need [6 international airports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airports_of_London) plus [16 general aviation airports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airports_of_London#Other_civil_airports)? I read it in an article recently. Are all of these civilian passenger flights or is there a mix of passenger, cargo and military?

Comment: I'd guess that some of them, for example 'London Oxford Airport' are calling themselves that for reasons of prestige rather than proximity - it's 62 miles from London!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_Airport

Comment: The two main answers give the commercial airports but there are also heliports e.g. Battersea and military e.g. Northolt.

Comment: @DaveGremlin Indeed, that would be like T.F.Green in Providence calling itself a Boston airport.

Comment: What’s ULCC? Please.

Comment: @Barmar Like Manchester-Boston Regional Airport (MHT)?

Comment: @DaveGremlin - though from where I live in North London, I could get to Oxford faster than I could get to Gatwick, and if I avoid CC/ULEZ/generally trying to cross the river other than at Dartford then probably a shorter distance too;)) I do usually try fly out of Stansted as my preference, & occasionally to similar 'satellite' airports… 'Berlin' Lübeck & 'Tokyo' Narita amongst the most memorably distant from their supposed city location.

Comment: Jemima: "I'm from Hammersmith, in London".  Mr. Darcy: "I'm familiar with a Hammersmith, but it's not anywhere near London."  - *Lost in Austen*

Comment: Jay Foreman did an [excellent video](https://youtu.be/AbAal7jIWQ4) on exactly this topic.

Comment: It's an enormous and busy place - shipping hub, travel hub, centre of British political power, international trading centre, home to ten million people *on an island*.  Why *wouldn't* London have six airports?

Comment: @GaspodetheIndomitable thank you for sharing that, although I do like the two-some in their mapmen series :)

Comment: @DaveGremlin: same for Paris: the *Aéroport Paris Beauvais* is also 62 miles away from Paris. It is in another **region** of France.

Comment: I consider the only airport that is truely in London to be London City Airport.

Comment: @Darren ULCC Ulta-Low-Cost-Carrier. Hope that clears that up :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-cost_carrier#Ultra_low-cost_carrier

Comment: @IanRingrose that's ok for you, But there are people from other countries and other places who would not consider say 62 miles/100 kms. or thereabouts to be a big distance, where the nearest distance to an International Airport is perhaps 250-300 or more kms. Entirely depends on circumstances, I suppose.

Comment: @WoJ That’s nothing, XCR/LFOK sometimes calls itself “Paris-Vatry airport”, and it’s 150 km from Paris.

Comment: @shirish: sure, but then you can hardly call it "airport [the place you drove from]"

Comment: @RomanOdaisky: ah yes, you are right, I forgot about that one. The funny thing is that right next to the word Paris, it clearly states it is 150 km away, in the Champagne Ardenne region :)

Comment: @DaveGremlin I don't think London Oxford Airport is typically one of "the 6". They are: Heathrow, Gatwick, Luton, Stansted, City, and Southend. I've never heard Oxford referred to as a London airport before today.

Comment: @Kidburla  You're right, it isn't one of the six, but it does use the name "London Oxford Airport"  https://www.oxfordairport.co.uk/business-aviation-3-4/

Answer (score 47):

The London area has [six international airports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airports_of_London): City, Heathrow, Gatwick, Luton, Stansted, and Southend, all offering commercial passenger flights. Some are rather far away from central London, however, and more than 70% of passengers travel through Heathrow or Gatwick. There's also a much larger number of airports in the area primarily used by general aviation.

The simplest explanation for this number is that a number of the airports are more-or-less at capacity (or at least were before the pandemic). London City has a single very short runway, cannot be practically expanded due to geography, and has a nighttime curfew, so it's pretty much doing all it can. Heathrow runs at nearly its full runway capacity, to the extent landing slots sold in the tens of millions of dollars pre-pandemic; [adding an additional runway at Heathrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_Heathrow_Airport) has been an extremely contentious issue for many years. Gatwick also uses a substantial portion of its runway capacity, and [was pushing plans before the pandemic to make use of an additional runway](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/gatwick-gets-watchdog-approval-to-add-50-000-flights-on-new-runway-jkv0d67nq) to accommodate more traffic. So that's three of the airports operating near capacity and yet still more travel demand: what's there to do but serve more airports?

Indeed, some of the less desirable airports like Luton are primarily used by low-cost carriers.

It's a lot of airports, but not uniquely. The New York (Newark, JFK, LaGuardia, Islip, White Plains, Stewart, plus charter flights in/out of Teterboro and other assorted options like the seaplane base) and Los Angeles (LAX, Burbank, Long Beach, Orange County, Ontario) metropolitan areas have roughly equivalent numbers of commercial airports as London. Cities with growing air travel demand can pretty much either keep expanding an airport with room to grow, distribute traffic among a larger number of regional airports, or embrace the megaproject of building a whole new airport somewhere farther away, and London has largely chosen the middle path.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127911/discussion-on-answer-by-zach-lipton-why-does-london-have-6-international-airport).

Answer (score 19):

This might be better suited for Aviation.SE, but I'll give it a crack anyway.  It really comes down to two things:

1. London is, by most measures, [the world's single largest blob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_busiest_city_airport_systems_by_passenger_traffic) (to use the technical term) of people who want to fly, with some 180 million passengers across those airports in 2019.  For comparison, the world's biggest single airports barely crack 100M, so it's clear you need at least two airports to handle the load.
2. Greater London is congested, unusually low-rise/sprawling and severely lacking in places to build new airports, much less expand old ones.

It's fairly common for a city to outgrow one airport and need to build a second one further away.  London has the rare distinction of having outgrown two airports simultaneously: Heathrow (in normal times, anyway) runs at full capacity and then some, with plans to build a third runway stuck in an endless bureaucracic quagmire, while Gatwick is stuck with a single runway and no way to expand that either.  Hence the growth of Luton, Stansted and recently Southend, which basically absorb the overflow that LHR/LGW cannot, and that's how London got to 5 airports.  Also, if you look at the map below, you can see that these five airports are in different cardinal directions, which also helps serve local passengers without requiring them to trek across the city.

[image]

(courtesy [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airports_of_London))

London's sixth airport, City, is a comparatively central and new operation developed primarily to serve business passengers doing short hops and willing to pay top dollar for the privilege.  Its runway is too short to cater to larger planes, so it serves only a fraction of the big boys' flights.

And that's really pretty much it for the airports with scheduled passenger services.  The remaining airfields in the greater London cater only to general aviation (private flight, hobbyists etc) and don't make much of a dent at all in that 180M figure.

Comment: (+1) Adding some information about [Croydon Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croydon_Airport) (closed 1959) might add some more insite on how an airport needs to involve accourding to the needs of a city (even if this is not a history site).

Comment: Also, there's a distinction between 'hub' airports such as Heathrow and Gatwick, and those which mainly provide point-to-point flights, such as Stansted.  With regard to capacity, Stansted has just had its upped from 35 million to 43 million, and the 35 was an increase from 28 million.  Stansted does see its spare runway capacity as a selling point  https://www.stanstedairport.com/about-us/london-stansted-airport-and-mag/facts-and-figures/

Comment: BA did offer a non-stop service between London City and JFK until the middle of last year.  But the fact that the service was all business-class and cost something in the range of [$5k-10k](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/100532/31165) sort of proves your point about it being an airport for the 1%.

Comment: IIRC it was only non-stop in one direction, because they couldn't take off from city with enough fuel for a transatlantic flight.

Comment: @PeterGreen Stopping at Shannon also let everyone go through US preclearance.

Answer (score 17):

Part of this creative naming and marketing/advertising tactics.

Low cost carriers try to avoid the higher fees of major airports like Heathrow or Gatwick. So they prefer cheaper airports that are in a less desirable place and don't have as good a connection to the city (Luton and Stansted). So when a low cost carrier decides to cover a popular market like London, they boost traffic at the more backwoods airports. They still want to be able to call it London and that determines the naming of the airport.

One of the more ridiculous examples is "Frankfurt Hahn" in Germany. This airport is closer to Luxembourg than it is to Frankfurt and it often takes two hours or more get from the airport to the city. It's just called "Frankfurt" so that the airlines can say they serve Frankfurt and their flights pop up in a Frankfurt-related search.

Ironically last time I flew out of Stansted I paid more for the bus from London to the airport than I paid for the flight!

Comment: Was thinking they all would have been connected by London Underground Railways. Guess that isn't so.

Comment: Only one (Heathrow) or two (also City) are connected underground. Those two and Gatwick by rail, although it is not far from Luton to the railway station of the same name. Connections improve over the years.

Comment: @Willeke: Stansted also has an efficient direct rail link to central London (c.50mins, £20) — so for most of NE London, Stansted is quicker by public transport than Heathrow or Gatwick.  It’s not at all comparable to really inconvenient airports like Frankfurt Hahn or Stockholm Skavsta.

Comment: @shirish the London Underground is slow (average speed 20 mph) and also very congested in central London.  Even the fastest underground line (Metropolitan) only reaches 60mph, and it doesn't connect with any of the airports. The reason for the slow average speed is that every train stops at every station.

Comment: @PLL, that is an improvement since I used the airport (at the time I had a friend living near, never used it for central London.) It used to be a long slog at the time, I am told.

Comment: @Willeke - just for completeness' sake, London City is not served by the London Underground, it's served by the DLR (Docklands Light Railway) a separate network (although with plenty of interchanges with the Underground). It actually makes the journey to City more enjoyable in my personal opinion - some of the views along the way are quite nice.

Comment: This is exactly the reason. "London Luton" and "London Southend" are just name changes, and existed for decades as "Luton Airport" and "Southend Airport". Biriths people still smile about this. My guess is that we are only a few years away from "London Birmingham" airport - maybe even "London Glasgow" airport.

Comment: DLR and the Underground are both run by Transport for London and ticketing is [somewhat] integrated. And Gatwick has been included as a Pay-as-you-go destination on Oyster (TFL's stored-value card) for five years or so.

Comment: @PLL. Fascinating Aïda have a song about that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVASZ2lCY5Y

Comment: @shirish London Underground a) doesn't go out anywhere near that far (especially to the south, where Gatwick is), and b) a lot of it is above ground, but still slow, so national rail is often the better choice

Comment: Another ridiculous example: I once booked a flight to "Brussels" on Ryanair. Brussels to Ryanair apparently is synonymous with Charleroi, 60 minutes via car or train. And it's not like London, where it can be argued that there is a metropolitan area that share the airport and the cities - there's a good 60km of field in between the two cities.

Comment: When Southend Airport was renamed to include ‘London’, they justified the name by pointing out that with its small, streamlined terminal, low passenger numbers, and proximity (60m!) to a mainline rail station with direct trains to a London terminus, you could land at Southend and be in central London faster than if you'd landed at Heathrow, despite the greater distance.  In that light, perhaps the name seems more reasonable.

Comment: Exactly, the fastest trains from heathrow to a London terminal are 20 minuites, gatwick is 30, standstead 49m. Luton is 45m (including the shuttle bus to the station), southend is 53m city doesn't have a train service but the rail planner quotes a DLR "fixed link" at 24 minuites (in reality it's probablly faster, because fixed links tend to be pessimistic). Given the amount of time-wasting BS surrounding air travel, 30 minuites can easilly be in the noise.

Comment: Oxford airport is pushing to be recognized as a london airport for the same reasons as southend.

Comment: Related: [What is the most remote airport from the center of the city it supposedly serves?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137558/what-is-the-most-remote-airport-from-the-center-of-the-city-it-supposedly-serves)

Comment: @Spratty By "London City", do you mean City of London?

Comment: @Acccumulation - "London City" is the name of the airport, probably to avoid confusion with the "City of London" itself, which is the (mainly) financial district also known as the "Square Mile".

Comment: @DJClayworth a screw-up with online adverts once led to me seeing flight adverts targeted at somewhere in Asia that were advertising flights to London (Manchester)

Comment: Some other fun ones where the name is everything: Maastricht Airport (the Netherlands) was renamed to Maastricht-Aachen Airpoirt some 20 years ago. It is very close to Maastricht, Aachen isn't in the Netherlands. It is across the border in Germany. And in the south of the Netherlands there is "Breda International Airport" which is a small general aviation field with delusions of grandeur to the locals better known under its original name "Seppe". It has a couple of business travelers (once a week or so) who own their own sports-plane and will fly to Brussels. Very "international".

Answer (score 11):

#### Mostly due to the Second World War

Whilst Heathrow and Gatwick were already significant civilian airports before 1939, the other airports either were small local operations or did not exist.

During WWII, a huge number of new airfields were constructed.  Smaller fighters could use flat grassed fields, but takeoff on a concrete runway was easier; and heavy bombers absolutely required concrete runways.  Hundreds of substantial airfields were constructed around the UK.  Distributing bases around the country allowed for faster local response times by interceptors and reduced the chances of damage by enemy bombing raids.

Post-war, the rising demand for air travel required runways for passenger aircraft, and it made sense to reuse existing runways from the war. Luton, Stansted and Southend airports are the legacy of this.  A selected number of airbases were retained for use by the RAF (and later by the USAF), such as Biggin Hill and Mildenhall.  Some were retained for private civilian operations, such as Duxford.
The majority though were simply grassed over or removed altogether by farmers.  I used to fly hang-gliders at [Mendlesham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAF_Mendlesham), where one grass-covered runway (and an old Nissen hut hangar) still exists.

It is important to note too that branding of these airports as "London Stansted" and "London Luton" is relatively recent.  Of course their proximity to London has not changed! but the rebranding was believed to make them more attractive as destinations for non-UK passengers.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you would not want to use Luton, Southend or Stansted?

Comment: At least an hour's drive from the closest side of the city. Add another hour and a half from the opposite side. And that's with current transport links - it used to be way worse.

Comment: Would the potential savings in airfare be worth the inconvenience? 2 hour drive may be worth a 150 pounds savings (idk if that is the case though)

Comment: @NeilMeyer Sure, and living a little north of London myself, I've flown from Birmingham as an alternative flight. The question isn't whether it's cheaper to fly from somewhere further away, it's whether it should still be calling itself "London" when it's that far away.

Answer (score 5):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbAal7jIWQ4) is quite a good video on the subject that I recommend. In short:
London had built a whole bunch of airports for military purposes during the world wars, so London already had a lot of RAF airports to pick from to convert to normal airports.

After WW2, Heathrow was built, and Gatwick, as a backup airport. Luton airport existed since 1938, but it had still serviced other counties. However during the 1960s the demand for air travel skyrocketed, the current airports not being able to service all the load. Standsted was built. However it was farther away than Luton, which gave Luton the idea of marketing itself as London Luton airport.

London Southend ap was opened by a company (to make money, of course). Pretty much the same story with London city airport.

That's pretty much it, I hope I explained it well.

Comment: London City Airport is, actually, the only airport in London…

Comment: Daniel, thank you but that was already covered in the above. See my mapmen comment. Still, thank you for taking the effort.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the reason is that Heathrow has just two runways. Schiphol has six, Frankfurt and Paris CDG has four. Thus there is a market for smaller airports. None of them has more than one runway. At the link you provided you can clearly see the priority between them: LHR > LGY > STN > LTN.

Comment: Though one of Schipol's runways is so far to the west of the terminals, perhaps they'll start marketing it as a London airport ;)

Comment: @ZachLipton Seriously. Last time I landed on the west runway it took nearly 20 minutes to taxi to the gate. (Arrivals hall A, so the plane had to go the long way around.  It's much better if you go to hall H or I, but it can still take about 10 minutes of taxiing.

Comment: @Tonny 20 minutes is not unusual at JFK though the distance is much less than from Schiphol's newest runway.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is history. Basically, when airports were built around London, the airplanes were still small enough that all you needed was a grass field and a barn as a hangar. When longer runways became necessary, there was little room left. So London is served by six smaller international airports with a total of 7 runways.
In contrast, Schiphol is a single airport with 6 runways.

As Jay Foreman [explains in an episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbAal7jIWQ4) of his YouTube series *Unfinished London*, the first aerodrome, Hendon Aerodrome, was started in 1908. Other aerodromes followed. During both World Wars, the RAF (and their predecessor, the RFC), converted a lot of these to airbases.

As planes got bigger and runways needed to be longer, a lot of these smaller airports were no longer able to support those planes and closed. Heathrow was planned as a larger airport, but the advent of jumbo jets and the enormous increase in the number of passengers was not foreseen, so other airports had to come to their aid.

Most were RAF bases that were converted to airports. London City was built from scratch.